# get all routes from nest.js app from a script

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

Currently i save all my routes in a file after the projects starts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const adapter = new FastifyAdapter(fastifyInstance);
  adapter.register(fastifyMultipart, fastifyAdapterConfig);
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, adapter);

  // Collecting all the routes from the project
  const routesList: Array<{ method: string; url: string }> = [];
  app
    .getHttpAdapter()
    .getInstance()
    .addHook('onRoute', (route: Record<string, string>) => {
      if (!JSON.stringify(route).includes('"hide":true')) {
        routesList.push({ method: <string>route.method, url: <string>route.url });
      }
    });


  // Saving all routes into a file in a root of a project
  const routesFileName = 'mock_index.js';
  fs.writeFile(path.join(process.cwd(), routesFileName), JSON.stringify(routesList), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      logger.error(`File ${routesFileName} saving errors: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
      throw err;
    }
    logger.log(`Routes list is saved in a root folder in a file: ${routesFileName}`);
  });
}
```

But how can I save all my routes without starting a project, outside **bootstrap()**
for example from **yarn:generate-routes**.

```
"generate-routes": "node ./ci-cd/generate-routes.js",
```

The main problem is to get the list of routes in runtime.